# "Amint I" is this correct? Would you use it? If not, I welcome suggestions

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

First question, am I seeing this slang correctly? *amint I*

Second, is there an alternative way I should say it?

And if not, how would you write it?

"Well yeah, I’m standing here *amint I?*"

Comment: What's the source of this slang term, i.e. where did you encounter it?

Comment: Do you mean *amn't I*, short for *am not I* meaning *am I not*? A substitute for *aren't I*.

Comment: @nnnnnn That's why I am enjoying this site, I think you are right, and It looks way better then amint I.

Comment: @killingtime, I think is slang, I've heard it used, not sure if Websters would agree.

Comment: @KevinBLeigh Define "slang". I think you are using it to mean something curious.  Slang is  like telling somebody spouting arrant nonsense that that's just so much *phonus bolonus*, or saying you're *tight on clams* when you're broke. Is isn't merely casual speech. It's idiomatic expressions that means something special. Saying *She ain’t kiddin’* is never considered slang.

Comment: @Laurel, I think so, but is there a better way, should I rephrase?

Comment: @tchrist thanks, I didn't realize that